# How to handle incorrect credentials with google oauth2 Installed Application code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm implementing the authorization code flow for [Installed Application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).
Code is similar to snippet below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, 
                                                                                   JSON_FACTORY, 
                                                                                   IA_CLIENT,
                                                                                   IA_SECRET, 
                                                                                   Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
            .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        System.out.println(drive.about());
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Everything is working fine except in the case when I provide an invalid `client_id`. (I've the same issue if I use a json file and alter its content).
I get this get of error message from Google server:

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
client_id=573900000-hsoobsdsstem84tg8br4pmdsds.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://localhost:40441/Callback
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

... and the callback server never receives any feedback. So, the application
is still running endlessly.

I've looked at the `LocalServerReceiver` class but could find any way to provide a
timeout or any potential solution.

What's the cleanest way to handle this case ?

Comment: Don't you have like a checker if statement which checks the Auth sign-in is successful or not?

Comment: The local receiver is waiting for a return code but as the initial request fails, it never receives the successful (or not) code back from google.